# Can all the certificates in the certificate chain be same?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

When I'm trying to download certificates from one website using SSL, I found that all the certificates in the chain are same. Is that possible? If yes, what is meaning of that

Comment: By definition it is a chain because each certificate at one level signs the certificate at next level... so obviously they can not be the same certificate, except if it is a self signed one, but in which case the chain is of length 1. Also your question is not really programming related and hence offtopic here. You do not provide either enough information about what "download certificates from one website" means as practical steps, so it will be hard to help you. Also there are a lot of misconfigured HTTPS websites. Use an online checker such as https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for the information.... That is classified information so I could not share that site info. But I've encountered that case

Comment: Certificates are typically public and published in Certificate Transparency Log websites (except if using a purely internal private CA of course)

Comment: Thanks Patrick Mevzek

Comment: We can close this discussion